# How to Redirect to external url from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET MVC 4 Project

How to Redirect to external url from HTTP-->HTTPS from controller?
I can't just type:

```
var url = @"https://www.someurl.com"
return Redirect(url);
```

it doesn't work.

Also I've tried this:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(url)
{
  Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps
};
return Redirect(uri.ToString());
```

Comment: What *Doesn't Work* about it?  What results do you get instead?

Comment: it will work if you set uri.Port = -1; // buy default there will be 80 port, you need default protocol port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem now: I used

```
return Redirect(url);
```

but it was an action called from Ajax (my mistake not to remember it) so the correct solution was using:

```
return JavaScript("window.location = '" + url + "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I stumbled on the same problem: I have an MVC website running under **https** and I have some situations where I need to redirect to some external url which I recieve as a parameter and when this url is an **http** url - say http://www.somethingontheweb.com - the straightforward

```
return Redirect("http://www.somethingontheweb.com");
```

actually does not work because after all it looks like this redirect to **https**://www.somethingontheweb.com which does not exist at all usually.

Still don't know why it works like this but I've found this work around: I've resorted to
[meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

So I have a page: ***~/Views/Shared/DoRedirect.cshtml*** and here is its code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=@ViewBag.RedirectUrl" />
<title>redirecting</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>redirecting...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and then my Controller code is just

```
ViewBag.RedirectUrl = url;
return View("DoRedirect");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mark your action with [RequireHttps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute. And your link will be automatic redirected to https

```
public class AccountController:Controller 
{
    [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can redirect to this action from your code - [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Moreover you can check next thread for some extra idea - [Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](http://forums.asp.net/t/1760705.aspx/1).

Comment: But if I want to redirect to external Url on another domain?

Comment: It isn't your code? hm. Is it possible that it is destination server redirect you to http?

Comment: It's mine, but I still can't find out how to get to external url. If I use RedirectToAction(A) (and action "A" marked with [RequireHttps]) that lays near my Action, I can't get to this "A" action. It becomes invisible to mvc.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>PoC</title>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    function poc() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4) {                     
                if(this.status == 200 || this.status == 0) {
                    alert(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", "content://media/external/file/747");
        xhr.send();
    }
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="poc()"></body> 
</html>
```